# How to mass delete old reports? Options

Tags: reporting

I want to mass delete old reports that haven't been run in over a year. I am not a developer and do not want to learn IDE Eclipse. Is there another way using the DataLoader?

Answer (score 14):

With the summer 14 release, You can delete mass reports in salesforce.

In Setup, under Data Management > Mass Delete Records, select Mass Delete Reports and configure a filter to find reports that need to be deleted. 
Reports that you delete go into the recycle bin. They aren’t permanently deleted until you clear your recycle bin.

Note: You can’t mass-delete reports that are scheduled or are used in dashboards or analytic snapshots.

Comment: Awesome news :)

Comment: Any luck on folders

Comment: 2020 and this doesn't seem to work, in either Classic or Lightning

Answer (score 8):

Edit - this answer is **obsolete** as of Summer'14, please check [varun's one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12077/mass-delete-old-reports-using-the-dataloader/45465#45465) instead.

---

DataLoader won't help you because the `Report` table is not "deletable".

If you have exported a list of obsolete Report Ids (for example last run date over 1 year ago) you can use a simple trick to wipe them.

Access `https://na1.salesforce.com/(report Id)?delrep=1` and it will attempt to delete it (`delrep` is the name of "Delete" button on the report page). If you're familiar with clickety-click tools like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) - awesome, otherwise generate links in Excel and ask an intern for assistance ;)

It will **still** fail if report is used on a Dashboard and as far as I know fastest way to detect such dependency is Eclipse / Metadata API (because you just search directory full of XMLs looking for `Report_Name_With_Underscores`)... It's a very good initial sweep nonetheless.

---

I had to delete 1,200 reports that weren't run since 13 months (out of 4,000 total), that would be too horrible deployment to do with Eclipse (and if it'd fail every time it hits "used in Dashboard" I'd go nuts). Hardly anybody noticed (mostly developers who suddenly got faster response times in Eclipse ;)).

Comment: @AMM It might be somewhat outdated now, with Tooling API or maybe the Analytics API has something to delete reports... But it still works and luckily last time I had to do it was over year ago... I like your automation idea but I'd stick to my intern solution though :P

Answer (score 2):

Happy to be proven wrong, but from what I've read, it isn't possible with the Data Loader.

You need to move all the reports into a single folder and them delete them in that folder via the Force.com IDE (or Eclipse).

- Ideas: [Mass Delete Reports](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brn5AAC)
- Ideas: [Need way to mass delete reports: Enable Reports to Be Accessed by Data Loader](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Z7EiAAK)
- Ideas: [Mass delete check box on reports and dashboards](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000XiWPAA0)
- Ideas: [Mass move reports / Mass delete reports / Mass move documents / Mass delete docu](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrnPAAS)

Comment: Your first link says it was delivered, though maybe only through the Metadata API.

Comment: @MikeChale, yes, it does. My understanding is the reports need to be moved to a common folder (time consuming) and then deleted from there with the Force.com IDE or Metadata API.