# Anyway to Delete Mass reports in SF which sit in different folders?

Tags: reporting, bulk-delete

i think my title gives you the problem. I want to mass delete reports i belive you can do this via Eclipse IDE Plug-In, however i dont want to go down this route, is it possible to do it by using the Apex data loader or even demand tools ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to delete reports using data loader, if you attempt a delete on the Report SObject you will be greeted with:

> DML operation DELETE not allowed on Report

DemandTools only lets you manipulate the data as well.

There are a few alternative options in [How to mass delete old reports? Options](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12077/mass-delete-old-reports-using-the-dataloader?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

I have actually found a GREAT way to do this in bulk even if you don't have Eclipse.  It involves building a fairly simple destructivechanges.xml file and deploying it through Workbench.

First, you have to build your file.  You basically just need two datapoints:

1. The **DeveloperName** of the report (you can get this by querying the standard **Report** object).
2. The **DeveloperName** of the **Folder** the report is in (from the report object, confusingly, the folder id is the **Ownerid** field.  Then just query the standard **Folder** object and get the name from there).

Then just create a destructivechanges.xml that looks like this in your favorite text editor (I use Sublime).  Pay special attention that you use the correct slash in between the folder and report names:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>FolderDeveloperName1/ReportDeveloperName1</members>
        <members>FolderDeveloperName2/ReportDeveloperName2</members>
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

Also create a package.xml that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

Put both files in a folder name src and zip it up (make sure you are doing it as a .zip file).

Now go to https://workbench.developerforce.com and go to **Migration--Deploy**.  Click **Choose File** and upload your zip file.  I recommend doing this in test first just to be sure you did it right.  Click **Next** and it will run.  All the reports you have specified will be deleted once the deployment is finished.  It is glorious.